# Using 60 frames per second causes the screen to leave a drawn trail of textures, when there is movement

Tags: libgdx, frame-rate, spritebatch

I'm trying to implement a frame rate feature, and I have noticed that using 60 frames per second causes the screen to leave a drawn trail of textures, when there is movement.

Here's the code I'm using to make the frame rate feature:

```
public void render(float deltaT){
    currentLevel.updateWorld(deltaT);

    if((fps+=deltaT) >= 1.0/60.0){
        fps = 0;
    }else
        return;

    super.render(deltaT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(103 / 255f, 69 / 255f, 117 / 255f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    currentLevel.updateScreen(deltaT, gameCamera);
}
```

The `currentLevel.updateWorld` updates the game's logic.
The `currentLevel.updateScreen` method updates the camera's position, drawn to the screen.

Comment: @Charanor Hi, I'm trying to limit frame rate while using the normal render speed for the game's logic, is there any other way to do this besides what I'm doing?
I've tried turning vSync ON but it still gives me a sprite trail when the my character moves.

Comment: @Joao there's no real reason to limit one but not the other. Not limiting the framerate will just increase your CPU load and use unnecessary resources and battery (if you're on mobile) for no real gain. As for the sprite trail that's probably a render problem so you will have to supply your rendering code if we're to help you fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to limit the framerate yourself within LibGDX. The framework handles that for you. You can enable vsync in your game by adding this line to your desktop configuration:

```
config.vSyncEnabled = true;
```

Or in-game using

```
Gdx.graphics.setVSync(true);
```